# powershell breaks at 180 characters

Tags: powershell, websocket

I have a file, **lorem.txt**, with the following

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, latine apeirian molestiae eieum. Reque clita laudem at quo, dicat petentium disputationi eum an. His cu latine adolescens, agam diceret senserit sea at, utinam utamur salutatus eos cu. Solum fuisset suscipit eu ius. Qui tollit ubique conceptam cu, ne his nullam postulant.
```

https://github.com/joewalnes/websocketd

```
UPDATED
```

When i run the following using websocketd, it breaks the string at 80 characters:

```
websocketd.exe powershell "Get-Content lorem.txt"
```

the websocket frames are chopped into 80 character chunks.  There any way I can force the powershell command to not use the default 80 character width?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have the same issue with `powershell "Get-Content lorem.txt | Set-Content out.txt"`?

Comment: No.  I checked my cmd properties and the 180 comes from my width set there.  So that expalins that.  However I just used the fileout as an example.  I've updated my question to reflect the entire problem.  Sorry for assuming the relevent information.

Answer (score 0):

`>` sends the standard output to the file. This output is probably limited by the size of the console(powershell) window. To store output from powershell, you should use a powershell cmdlet like `Out-File`. Ex:

```
powershell "Get-Content lorem.txt | Out-File out.txt"
```

`Out-File` also has a `-Width` parameter where you could specify the character-limit for eac line.